# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined (ANGULAR 14.2.1)

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an SSR angular app built with V14.2.1
In my gateway, I have a method that returns a GET request.

```
const url = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class SampleGateway {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

  getData(id:number): Observable<SomeInterface> {

  let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
  params = params.set('id',id);

  return this.httpClient.get<SomeInterface>(`${url}/entity`, {params: params});

  }

}
```

The app builds successfully on the server-side but when this method is called on one of the pages I get this `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined (ANGULAR 14.2.1)` error and the page doesn't load.

If I remove `options` from the request it works correctly.

```
return this.httpClient.get<SomeInterface>(`${url}/entity`);
```

What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dont forget import HttpParams and if you try to set() to params you must define new variable too.
```

```html
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

getParams(id): Observable<any> {

    let params = new HttpParams().set('id', id);

    return this._HttpClient.get(`${url}/entity`, { params: params })
}
```

Comment: You mean I didn't import anything? I did import. I mentioned that it builds successfully.

Comment: no I mean you have to import HttpParams too, If you already imported then there must be a problem in syntax , this syntax that I sent works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you. It's fine from every aspect, syntax and import. I really don't know why it's happening. It even works on development.